Super mario bros NES PAL version 99 lives trick (turtle tipping) not working
I have come across a lot of references mentioning the trick: Where is the infinite (99) lives staircase in the original Super Mario Bros?
I tried a lot and never achieved the trick with my PAL-E console. Then I went to emulator (retroarch mesen core) and tried both US and EU version. It does actually work in US NTSC version. I also tried in EU version with emulator and doesnt work there either. Is there a way to do it in PAL version or is it patched in EU version?

PAL and NTSC ran at different framerates, so it's possible the timing just doesn't work in PAL. I'm not familiar enough with the differences between the SMB versions to know if this truly affects anything.
